# Adding fully connected layer after lstm layer in keras

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am trying to build the model using `LSTM` using `keras`. The model structure, which I want to build, is described in the picture.[image: The first layer is LSTM layer]

In keras, I know to create such a kind of LSTM layer I should the following code.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(3,1), return_sequences=True))
```

4 is the output size from each LSTM cell. `return_sequence` configure `many to many` structure. But I do not know how I should add the Dense layer to get all information from the LSTM cells and output multiple neurons. I do not know even is it possible or not. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on SimonC's answer. You can add a Flatten layer. Depending on your purpose, it may have different ways

```
def model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, input_shape = (LSTM_WINDOW_SIZE,1)))
    model.add(LSTM(units=5,
                   return_sequences=True))

    model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear'))
    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(1))
    return model
LSTM_WINDOW_SIZE = 5
model3 = model()
model3.summary()
```

or (move the `Flatten` layer before `Dense` layer)

```
def model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, input_shape = (LSTM_WINDOW_SIZE,1)))
    model.add(LSTM(units=5,
                   return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear'))

    model.add(Dense(1)) # redundant for this model, just for illustration
    return model
LSTM_WINDOW_SIZE = 5
model3 = model()
model3.summary()
```

Comment: Adding the flatten layer solved my problem. The Flatten layer is fully connected to the next Dense layer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to have a many to many output you could use [TimeDistributed](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/) Dense layers. If it is okay to just look at the last output (from the last timestep) you can remove the return_sequences=True and just plug in a Dense layer (altough it would than be many to one)

Comment: Thanks, that is an alternative model that I try. But I want to build this one. Outputs come from each LSTM cells, and then fully connected layer which gets all information.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a Dense layer after your LSTM layer, **without setting 'return_sequences' to False** (this is only needed if you have a second LSTM layer after another LSTM layer). I made an LSTM model recently to predict some future values, depending on the history of that variable. This worked fine for me:

```
def model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, input_shape = (LSTM_WINDOW_SIZE,1)))
    model.add(LSTM(units=5,
                   return_sequences=False)
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('linear'))

return model
```

You can delete the first Dense layer if you want.

Comment: I am interested in the model described in the picture if It is possible.

Comment: I cannot give you the full assignment, since it was made for university purposes. Can I help you by answering further questions?

Comment: My main question is how to add a fully connected layer after the lstm layer like the picture I described. I am not even sure is It possible to build. But It is the task to search for it.

Comment: `model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(3,1), return_sequences=True)) model.add(Dense(1))`

Comment: here the last Dense layer gives one output from each LSTM cell but not one output from all LSTM cells